# JQuery datatable how to do search multiple value within single column using OR logic

Tags: jquery, datatable

for example, there is a column index of 7 about Source. I want to filter out all Source from A or B to be my result by typing A,B in the search input box.
the format A,B is flexible, it can be A|B, A B.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use regexp:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6946/multiple-filters-on-same-column

Go to:
http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html

- In column: Column - Office
- Put: tokyo|london
- And check: Treat as regex

Comment: I am facing the same problem. In my application i want to implement search in same column for multiple values.  I have referred the regEx option to filter.
It is working fine when i am searching with value ----  tokyo|london.
but it is not working when i am searching with  ----tokyo|london|San Francisco.

the probable reason is San Francisco contains space character in it.
but in my application the values may contain space character. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi @Dip686, try to disable smart parameter when calling the [search api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())

Answer (score 12):

**100% Working** Multiple value search single column

```
var oTable = $('#intrestTable1').DataTable( {});
oTable.column(5).search("caod|bullet",true,false).draw();
```

Comment: this worked for me without mentioning regex search as mentioned in dataTables.net site