# How to search multiple values in a column of Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've created a filter with multiple select for filtering names is datatables.

The filter looks like this :

```
 $("#filter").on('change', function() {
            //filter by selected value on second column
     table.column(1).search($(this).val()).draw();
  });
```

P.s - the duplicate post answer doesn't contains a working example.

How can  i pass multiple values to the .search() method ?

Like this :

```
   $("#filter").on('change', function() {

     table.column(1).search(multiple values).draw(); // Search multiple values
    });
```

My project is [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VZizdhY8RS9Eqp9JyOio?p=preview),

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery datatable how to do search multiple value within single column using OR logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812500/jquery-datatable-how-to-do-search-multiple-value-within-single-column-using-or-l)

Comment: Already checked there - didn't found what i was looking for.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8z6eh3o9/) what you are looking for?

Comment: From the syntax i did found some good ideas... but i don't know if the example is working properly - when i  typed "Cedric Kelly Airi Satou" - it didn't found any results...and it didn;t worked on my project either

Comment: My bad. The replace only replaced the first occurrence. [Check this updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/8z6eh3o9/1/). (But this is part of the answer I marked as possible duplicate.)

Comment: Hi - i added your code to my project but i still can't make it works....https://plnkr.co/edit/VZizdhY8RS9Eqp9JyOio?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143253/discussion-between-roybaron-and-ivar).